# Macro, Capturing mouse and Keyboard

Tags: java

I Need to make a macro, for capturing mouse and keyboard in JAVA.

I can work with macros without using API?
if not,which API should I use?

Comment: Does it have to be macro?

Comment: i need to automate some functions of the company...

Comment: Got it, just asking because I know capturing but not in macros

Comment: There are listeners for various input sources. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for example. You can capture what the user does and then replicate it using [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).